# How do you call a Kubernetes REST service internally?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to schedule a cron job in a Kubernetes environment and I want to access the service internally instead of through the load balancer outside the cluster. Here's an example of my Service definition in YAML:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: stage-api-svc
  labels:
    run: stage-api
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-protocol: "http"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-redirect-http-to-https: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-tls-ports: "443"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-sticky-sessions-cookie-name: "stage-cloud"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-sticky-sessions-cookie-ttl: "380"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-healthcheck-path: "/status"
spec:
  selector:
    special: stage-api-svc
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
```

I've read in other comments to similar questions that I can use the `special` selector to reference the service. In my case, I would call:

```bash
curl -H "InternalUser: true" -X GET "http://stage-api-svc:8443/cron"
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working, so I'm wondering if I'm using the correct value for the selector in the service definition to reference it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to access the service within the k8s cluster, you should use use service port `443` instead of `8443`. Also make sure that:

- Service's `targetPort` is correctly mapping to Pod's container port
- Both Service and Pod(s) are in same namespace. If they are in different NS, mention it in url as well like `http://stage-api-svc.namespace-name:443/cron`
- `selectorLabels` used in `Service` are pointing correctly to Pod's labels.